# How do I access a PHP file in public_html directory from my HTML code?

Tags: php

I have a HMTL form in which I am calling a PHP file for inserting data into a MYSQL database.

Where do I put the file on the webserver? Do I put it in public_html directory?

```
<form id="XXXForm" method="POST" action="xxx.php">
```

[File structure with permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylIyz.jpg)

Comment: Are you looking for opinions? You can put the file wherever you want really, as long as you can access it.

Comment: Well maybe I didn't explain it properly.. When I put the file in the public_html folder, and run my HTML form, I get the message file not found. The file is present in the public_html folder.

Comment: Why don't you share the code as it appears in your form, and include maybe a screenshot of the directory structure as you see it in an FTP program.  Include file ownership and read/write permissions if you can.

Comment: Just added a snapshot of the directory structure and the line of code where I am calling the PHP file from my HTML code.

Comment: thanks for the screenshot, but can you include the ownership permissions?  If root owns the file, then with cPanel, it may not be executable.

Comment: Uploaded the screenshot again with the permissions. Realised the permissions were not present in the previous screenshot.

Comment: Now we know where your xxx.php is located; what about the document that contains the form?

Comment: @04FS I have written HTML code in a WordPress page.

Comment: And what is the URL of that page?

Comment: Most likely you just need `action="/xxx.php"` …

Comment: @04FS I have tried that. Does not work. Get the same error - File not found.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You should put file inside `public_html`.You can only access file inside of `public_html` folder.

Comment: For some reason the file is not accessible from my HTML form. I get the message xxx.php file not found.

Comment: If you use `action="xxx.php"`, file xxx.php should be in the same folder as the file that contains the form. Else use `action="/xxx.php"`

Comment: @ALFA the file that contains the form code is a WordPress page.

Comment: @DavidD'Lima wordpress page is just a virtualization of a real file that points you to the wanted direction. If you don't know which file is handling wordpress pages rely on the second solution which is to put `xxx.php` in `public_html` and use `action="/xxx.php"` in your form.

Comment: Already tried that. Does not work. Still get the error file not found.

Comment: If you are using wordpress then add your php file in current theme folder as below.

_/public_html/wp-content/themes/current_theme_name_ then you can access php file.

Comment: @BhaveshPatel i put the file in the path mentioned by you. in my html code and I get  ERROR 500 Internal Error. Is this to do with permissions?

Comment: Guys any help is greatly appreciated. Been struggling with this for  a while.

Comment: @DavidD'Lima if you are getting ERROR 500  then you have might PHP side error. Please make simple php file and debug.

Comment: @BhaveshPatel thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Problem solved. Issue was with a php file I was using for testing which was not in public_html folder. No issues of permission. Silly mistake.